# How to categorize selected numbers in one column and represent them in the form of categories in a new column in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to categorize numbers in the column (mbs_item_number) and represent them in a new column (item_cat) in the form of category.

I used the following code for categorizing few numbers to category '1'.

```
df$item_cat[mbs_item_number = c(10,12,13,15)] <- 1
```

I am experiencing the following error message:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, item_cat, value = c(NA, NA, NA, 1,  : 
  replacement has 10943 rows, data has 122412
```

Answer (score 2):

Here, we can use `%in%` (used when the length of the `vector` to be compared is more than 1, if it is `1`, then `==`) instead of the assignment opertor (`=`)

```
df$item_cat[mbs_item_number %in% c(10,12,13,15)] <- 1
```

Comment: Hi akrun, thank you. It worked! But a small improvement df$item_cat[df$mbs_item_number %in% c(10,12,13,15)] <- 1